# Using variables in the Jinja2 template in ansible Playbook

Tags: scripting, ansible, jinja2

Any idea of how we can use dynamic variables inside the Jinja2 Template. Below is the data from my Jinja2 template.

`oracle.install.asm.diskGroup.disks=/dev/oracleasm/disks/DATA,/dev/oracleasm/disks/ARCH,/dev/oracleasm/disks/OCR`

The variable values in the `defaults/main.yml` is:

```
     asm_disk_detail:
     - { name: 'OCR', path: '/dev/sde1' }
     - { name: 'DATA', path: '/dev/sdf1' }
     - { name: 'ARCH', path: '/dev/sdg1' }
```

I am trying to use these variable values to pass dynamically at the time of running the playbook. These values should automatically get populated in the template.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. The main.yml will be sourced automatically when the ansible role is invoked. You just have to write a jinja2 template file for the same.

For example the below file:

A better representation of the main.yml file would be

```
---
asm_disk_detail:
- name: OCR
  path: "/dev/sde1"
- name: DATA
  path: "/dev/sdf1"
- name: ARCH
  path: "/dev/sdg1"
```

jinja2 template: supports for loop so you can apply with_items on the above variable asm_disk_detail and create a config file as needed.

Note:- Please try the jinja2 file creation from your side in case any issues please shout :)

===============Play and jinja2 template

playbook-->

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: test
      include_vars: vars.yml
    - name: jinja2
      template:
        src: template/template.yml
        dest: target/target.yml
```

jinja2-->

```
{%- for item in asm_disk_detail -%}
{%- if not loop.last -%}
{{ item.path }}/{{ item.name }},
{%- else -%}
{{ item.path }}/{{ item.name }}
{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

output-->

```
oracle.install.asm.diskGroup.disks=/dev/sde1/OCR,/dev/sdf1/DATA,/dev/sdg1/ARCH
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..! My Template has the following line..!
        oracle.install.asm.diskGroup.disks=/dev/oracleasm/disks/{{ item }},/dev/oracleasm/disks/{{ item }},/dev/oracleasm/disks/{{ item }}.

My vars file containes the below lines.
        asm_disk_detail:
     - { name: 'OCR', path: '/dev/sde1' }
     - { name: 'DATA', path: '/dev/sdf1' }
     - { name: 'ARCH', path: '/dev/sdg1' }

The line in the template has to fetch the value from  vars file, which is not working for me. I tried using For loop as well. @error404

Comment: @IOT Added the play, jinja2 template and the output format I am generating. Let me know in case you are looking for another output format

Answer (score 1):

Use Ansible [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) with a [For loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) in your template.

```
{% for disk in asm_disk_detail %}
  disk name: {{ disk.name}}
  disk path: {{ disk.path }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Here it,s taking the same name for the 3 variables. @sebthebert